# How can I return the results of a function to a cell in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

Suppose I have a function attached to one of my Excel sheets:

```
Public Function foo(bar As Integer) as integer
    foo = 42
End Function
```

How can I get the results of `foo` returned to a cell on my sheet? I've tried `"=foo(10)"`, but all it gives me is `"#NAME?"`

I've also tried `=[filename]!foo(10) and [sheetname]!foo(10)` with no change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following the directions [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20090220142331/http://exceltip.com/st/Writing_Your_First_VBA_Function_in_Excel/631.html) to make sure you're doing everything correctly, specifically about where to put it. ( `Insert->Module` )

I can confirm that opening up the VBA editor, using `Insert->Module`, and the following code:

```
Function TimesTwo(Value As Integer)
    TimesTwo = Value * 2
End Function
```

and on a sheet putting `"=TimesTwo(100)"` into a cell gives me `200`.

Answer (score 3):

Put the function in a new, separate module (Insert->Module), then use =foo(10) within a cell formula to invoke it.

Comment: I got the same result for both options

Answer (score 1):

Where did you put the "foo" function?  I don't know why, but whenever I've seen this, the solution is to record a dimple macro, and let Excel create a new module for that macro's code.  Then, put your "foo" function in that module.  Your code works when I follow this procedure, but if I put it in the code module attached to "ThisWorkbook," I get the #NAME result you report.

Answer (score -1):

include the file name like this

```
=PERSONAL.XLS!foo(10)
```

Comment: Same result both with my actual file name or with personal.xls